# Searching for a Netsuite InboundShipment using SuiteTalk

Tags: c#, netsuite, suitetalk

I am trying to do a search to find out if there is an existing InboundShipment in NetSuite with a given ExternalDocumentValue.

The problem I am having is the ExternalDocumentNumber is a string but the InboundShipmentSearch seems to be wanting a RecordRef array and I do not know what value to create the recordRef with.    Here is my current code

```
        InboundShipmentSearchAdvanced isa = new InboundShipmentSearchAdvanced();
       // isa.criteria.basic.externalDocumentNumber.searchValue = 

        InboundShipmentSearchBasic ts = new InboundShipmentSearchBasic();
        Client.SearchPreferences.bodyFieldsOnly = false;

        isa.criteria = new InboundShipmentSearch();
        isa.criteria.basic = new InboundShipmentSearchBasic();
        isa.criteria.basic.externalDocumentNumber = new SearchMultiSelectField();
        isa.criteria.basic.externalDocumentNumber.@operator =SearchMultiSelectFieldOperator.anyOf;
        List<RecordRef> rrlist = new List<RecordRef>();
        RecordRef rr = new RecordRef();  RecordType.
        rr.name = "HJ_InboundShip_1";  // I don't think this is what I need to prime the record ref. 
        rrlist.Add(rr);
        isa.criteria.basic.externalDocumentNumber.searchValue = rrlist.ToArray();
```

The issue is since that value is a string and does not really seem to relate to any linked record in the schema, I don't know how to set up the rec. ref for the search.   I wondered if anyone had any idea of what I would need to do that.

Answer (score 0):

RecordRef's are a way to define a record lookup for links to existing records, and need instantiation with the either the internalid or externalid of the record. See [SuiteAnswers id 10801](https://netsuite.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/10801/kw/recordref).